# Ant task fails to send email on one computer on another it is successful

Tags: email, ant

I've got this ant task working(sending email) on my machine :

```
<project name="send_mail_test" default="send_mail_test">
<property name="report" value="${report}" />
<property name="build" value="${build}" />
<property name="env" value="${env}" />
<property name="resultFile" value="${resultFile}" />

<target name="send_mail_test">
    <mail encoding="mime" mailhost="mailserver.intranet.lan" subject="[REPORT] ${build} on ${env} environment - Test report" tolist="test@intranet.lan">
<!-- FROM and REPLY TO email addresses -->
      <from address="mailman@intranet.lan"/>
      <replyto address="noreply@intranet.lan"/>

      <message>Some body message

      </message>

      <attachments>
        <fileset dir="${report}" includes="${resultFile}.html"/>
      </attachments>
    </mail>
</target>
</project>
```

This is how I start the above script to run(send_mail.xml) :

```
ant -f send_mail.xml -Dreport=C:\TESTING\results -Denv=DEV -Dbuild=1.0.1 -DresultFile=result-2012-07-17-11-03-25.html
```

It's successful from my computer(windows 7), but from another windows xp it's not. This is the error that I get :

```
Buildfile: C:\TESTING\setup\send_mail.xml

send_mail_test:
     [mail] Sending email: [REPORT] C:\TESTING\results on DEV environment - Test report
     [mail] Failed to send email: Could not connect to SMTP host: mailserver.intranet.lan, port: 25

BUILD FAILED
C:\TESTING\setup\send_mail.xml:8: Problem while sending mime mail:

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I realize that I cannot connect to the mailserver, but what do I do? What do I take a look at the possible reason for not being able to connect?

SOLUTION : I installed linux on this box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- check network connections
- check reachability of other services
- check firewall settings (especially for the java executable running ant)
- check if the problem is temporary
- check if it is still possible to do this from the other machine, may be the mail-server is down
- talk to someone that is responsible for the network - if it's not you